# How can I transfer data through the IP address to web server?

Tags: sql, apache, web-services, ip

I have created a Apache web server with dedicated IP, how can I transfer data to the web server using that web server IP address and port? How can I set up a php socket to received data through IP and save as a text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're always using the IP to contact a server. If you use a url, the domain name is looked up in a DNS and you still use the IP to connect to the server.

After that, in the request, the domain name (or URL actually) is specified, and based on the existence and value of that information the server may allow or deny the request.

It's not a matter of 'not possible', it's just how you configure your server.